# login instagram simpletest PHP

Tags: php, browser, authentication, instagram, simpletest

i have a problem, i'm trying to connect to instagram with the scriptable web browser simpletest: http://www.simpletest.org

But i have an error:

> This page could not be loaded. If you have cookies disabled in your
>   browser, or you are browsing in Private Mode, please try enabling
>   cookies or turning off Private Mode, and then retrying your action.

Can you help me please ?

There is my code:

```
<?php
require_once('simpletest/browser.php');

$browser = new SimpleBrowser();
$browser->useCookies();
$browser->useFrames();
$page = $browser->get('https://instagram.com/accounts/login/?force_classic_login');
$browser->setFieldByName("username", "my login");
$browser->setFieldByName("password", "my password");
$browser->click("Log in");
$page = $browser->getContent();
echo $page;

?>
```

Thank's a lot.

Comment: Do you have cookies disabled, or are you browsing in private mode? ;)

Comment: That login page does not appear to work with a normal browser?!

Comment: @GeorgeQ yes it work in normal browser, but not with simpletest.. :/

Comment: @Luke "$browser->useCookies();" yes the cookies are allowed.

Comment: Perhaps instagram doesn't like the user agent...? I'm just shooting in the dark now, though. Does this work for other websites?

Comment: @Luke yes it work for some websites.

Comment: Did you solve this?